# How to use React Native launch options parameter for RCTRootView

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am not a JS or React programmer but I need to use it for my project.

I want to pass in values to my React views from my native code so that it will be rendered by the React engine.

I've tried many variations

My native code looks like:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"ReactTesting"
                                                   launchOptions:@{@"initialProps" : @"<Text>Hello from native code</Text>"}];

rootView.initialProperties = @{@"initialProps" : @"<Text>Hello from native code</Text>"}; // ???
```

And in my react code i want to render that JSX:

```
var ReactForTesting = React.createClass( {

render: function() {
  return (The Launch Options that were sent to this view); //How do I render it?
  }
});
```

I've tried returning various things in the render function - none would render:

```
render : function () {
  return this.props; // doesn't work
}

render : function () {
  return this.props.initialProps; // doesn't work
}

render : function () {
  return this.props.initialProps; // doesn't work
}

also fiddling with:
React.createElement()
React.createClass()..
```

Answer (score 4):

In AppDelegate.m:

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                             moduleName:@"ReactTesting"
                                             launchOptions:launchOptions];

NSDictionary *initialProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"Hello from native code" forKey: @"myProp"];

rootView.initialProperties = dict;
```

Then you can access `this.props.myProp` in whichever component you passed to `AppRegistry.registerComponent`.

Not sure why you're trying to pass a <Text> node through in your string though, that seems like a bad idea. Just pass the text content then use the <Text> component on the JS side.

Comment: I want to get the nodes from a server (as a string) and let React handle rendering them. Otherwise i will need to create a parser in my react code for understanding the text (description of the nodes) and emit proper react code for producing the tags

Comment: That's not going to work, you will receive a string from the Obj-C side, they won't be components. You'll still have to parse the string.

Comment: Ok . thanks. Do you know of a way to compile the JSX on the device rather by the node server?

Comment: I'd open a new question on that and we can discuss it there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I have fixed this problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2100

You can just define those initial props in a `settings.plist`

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I would like to know why we have to set the root view  in our view controller other than app delegate? What is the use by setting the root view? Can you explain me  clearly Plz...